# "No symbols loaded" notification at break point in decompiled source using generated symbols

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

I'm trying to step/break into the line of code below while debugging:

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public abstract class CustomFormViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
        private DBContextModels.Models.DbBuildingContext _dbContext;

        public CustomFormViewModel()
        {
            ...

            // no symbols loaded, cannot step into
            _dbContext = new DBContextModels.Models.DbBuildingContext();
        }
    }
}
```

`DbBuildingContext` is defined in the assembly **DbContextModels.dll**, which I do not have source or symbol files for, so I'm trying to step into it's decompiled source using generated symbols.

Stepping into the above statement has no effect, it's just stepped over, and setting a break point within the `DbBuildingContext` constructor gives a *"no symbols loaded"* notification.

[image]

Using ReSharper, I generated a symbol file for **DbContextModels.dll**:

[image]

and stored it here

`"xxx\DbContextModels.pdb\E3D17590C9F44E73BC95AC40AB59EC891\DbContextModels.pdb"`

**"Show PDB Content"** reveals

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pdb Name="DbContextModels" 
 Path="xxx\DbContextModels.pdb\E3D17590C9F44E73BC95AC40AB59EC891\DbContextModels.pdb"  
 AssemblyPath="xxx\DbContextModels.dll" 
 SignatureFromAssembly="e3d17590-c9f4-4e73-bc95-ac40ab59ec89 " 
 PdbFileFromAssembly="xxx\notme\xxx\DbContextModels\obj\Debug\DbContextModels.pdb ">
  <UserEntryPoint>null</UserEntryPoint>
  ...
```

**Everything looks correct, except `UserEntryPoint` is *null* and `PdbFileFromAssembly` is pointing to the local path of the user who built the assembly. Should `UserEntryPoint` have a valid value, and should `PdbFileFromAssembly` match `Path`?**

**Note:** `E3D17590C9F44E73BC95AC40AB59EC891` and `e3d17590-c9f4-4e73-bc95-ac40ab59ec89` are nearly identical.

I configured the debugger options to load symbols for this assembly:

[image]

[image]

I also made sure that the ReSharper caches were cleared, and that the assembly showing in Assembly Explorer (which the symbol file was generated from) was pointing to the same location as the "loaded module" path in debug options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Modules** window I found that the Symbol Status was *"Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting"*.  Right-clicking on the module and selecting "Load Symbols" solved the issue:

[image]